# Is there a way to force SCons to overwrite copied directories?

Tags: scons

I have the following command to copy a directory of HTML files:

```
env.Command(target, source, [Copy('$TARGET', '$SOURCE'), Chmod('$TARGET', 0755)])
```

This copies the directory to the correct location as I expect. But if I make a change to a file, the file does not have the new contents after I run the install again. Is there a way to force an overwrite?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please use the `env.Install()` method instead, and don't use directory names as `$SOURCE`. You'll have to *install* all your files single. Note that in SCons, like every other build system out there, a directory is up-to-date as soon as it exists.
So, once you copied your source folder it won't get updated anymore.

See also the [SCons FAQ](http://scons.org/faq.html), "*Why is my directory only updated the first time?*".